Does Spark infer partition of parquet file persisted using repartition() on reading?
I have two datasets stored as parquet files with schemas as below:
Dataset 1:



id
col1
col2




1
v1
v3


2
v2
v4



Dataset 2:



id
col3
col4




1
v5
v7


2
v6
v8



I want to join the two datasets using pyspark on the id field. Both the datasets are large with millions of records. Both the datasets have a single entry for any id value.
I want to store the datasets in such a way that when the pyspark job to join the two datasets is run, the shuffles are minimised. So before persisting Dataset 1 and Dataset 2, they were partitioned like:
dataset1.repartition(100, 'id')
dataset2.repartition(100, 'id')

The number of id values is large, so I cannot repartitionBy the id column, as that would lead to a large number of small files.
As per my understanding repartitioning would ensure that the same ids go to the same partition number of dataset1 and dataset2. If I read the data in the join job, partition 1 of dataset 1 and partition 1 of dataset 2 can be easily joined in memory if they contain the same ids. But this did not happen, and I could see a lot of shuffling happening in the join job.
Does spark infer this partition information from the parquet file? Is there a way I can make spark infer this information? Is there a better way to put the same id in the same partition number so that operations like joins can be optimised?

The functionality you're looking for is called bucketing and can be used via the bucketBy method. It's slightly different from regular partitioning, and means that you can load the datasets in & join them without needing to shuffle. The other answer notes that Spark can read partition information for a regular partitioned set of Parquet files. While this is technically true, that info is used primarily for partition pruning. Having to use repartition is the same thing as a shuffle, so it doesn't achieve what you want.
In contrast, for joins or aggregations, where a hash partitioning into a specific number of partitions needs to happen, bucketBy is the right choice.
We can demonstrate the difference with example code in the Spark shell.
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", "-1")

val data = Seq(
  (1, "A"),
  (2, "B"),
  (3, "C"),
  (4, "A"),
  (5, "B")
)
val df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF("id", "category")

Since we're using a small test dataset, we disable broadcast joins so that Spark's planner will use a standard sort-merge join, which typically requires a shuffle.
Our test query will be to self-join the test dataset to itself on the category column,
val dfSelfJoin = df.join(df, Seq("category"))

Using dfSelfJoin.explain shows the plan includes Exchange hashpartitioning (a hash partitioning + shuffle, using Spark's default of 200 partitions) & a sort within each partition before the two are joined:
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Project [category#5, id#4, id#19]
   +- SortMergeJoin [category#5], [category#20], Inner
      :- Sort [category#5 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(category#5, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=77]
      :     +- LocalTableScan [id#4, category#5]
      +- Sort [category#20 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
         +- Exchange hashpartitioning(category#20, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=78]
            +- LocalTableScan [id#19, category#20]

Now, if we write the DataFrame to Parquet, read it back in, and try the self-join again,
repartitionedDF.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").save("testDF")

val readDF = spark.read.parquet("testDF")

val readDFSelfJoin = readDF.join(readDF, Seq("category"))

we can see the planner still wants to reshuffle the data before joining:
readDFSelfJoin.explain
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Project [category#25, id#24, id#28]
   +- SortMergeJoin [category#25], [category#29], Inner
      :- Sort [category#25 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(category#25, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=117]
      :     +- Filter isnotnull(category#25)
      :        +- FileScan parquet [id#24,category#25] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(category#25)], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/testDF], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(category)], ReadSchema: struct<id:int,category:string>
      +- Sort [category#29 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
         +- Exchange hashpartitioning(category#29, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=118]
            +- Filter isnotnull(category#29)
               +- FileScan parquet [id#28,category#29] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(category#29)], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/testDF], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(category)], ReadSchema: struct<id:int,category:string>

This shows that Spark doesn't infer the partitioning correctly when reading regular Parquet files, even if they were partitioned before writing.
However, if we save the table with bucketBy, read it in, and try the same self-join,
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.bucketing.autoBucketedScan.enabled", "false")

readDF.write.format("parquet").bucketBy(5, "category").sortBy("category").option("path", "/testBucketedTable1").saveAsTable("testBucketedTable1")

val bucketedTable = spark.read.table("testBucketedTable1")

val selfJoinBucketed = bucketedTable.join(bucketedTable, Seq("category"))

we see a different query plan:
selfJoinBucketed.explain
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- Project [category#73, id#72, id#76]
   +- SortMergeJoin [category#73], [category#77], Inner
      :- Sort [category#73 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :  +- Filter isnotnull(category#73)
      :     +- FileScan parquet spark_catalog.default.testbucketedtable1[id#72,category#73] Batched: true, Bucketed: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(category#73)], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/testBucketedDF1], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(category)], ReadSchema: struct<id:int,category:string>, SelectedBucketsCount: 5 out of 5
      +- Sort [category#77 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
         +- Filter isnotnull(category#77)
            +- FileScan parquet spark_catalog.default.testbucketedtable1[id#76,category#77] Batched: true, Bucketed: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(category#77)], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/testBucketedDF1], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(category)], ReadSchema: struct<id:int,category:string>, SelectedBucketsCount: 5 out of 5

Notice how there's no longer a hash-partition & exchange step. Spark will read the file in, filter for no nulls on the join key, sort within the partitions, and join.
To make this work with two different datasets, you'll need to ensure both are bucketed by the same column you want to join them on, and that the number of buckets (partitions) set in bucketBy is the same.
One more tip is that for the case where you have one dataset bucketed & want to join to another that isn't bucketed/partitioned, you can still avoid shuffling the bucketed table by setting spark.sql.shuffle.partitions to the bucketed table's number of buckets. This optimization can make sense when you have a large table you know in advance will be joined to many other tables on the same key.
This way, Spark will repartition the unpartitioned table into the same number of partitions as the bucketed table. At that point, both have the same number of partitions & hash key, so the two are joined without ever triggering a shuffle of the bucketed dataset. You may need to turn off Spark's adaptive query planning so that spark.sql.shuffle.partitions is not overridden when doing this.

Spark can infer partition information from the parquet file, but it might not be the optimal partitioning for a particular job. In your case, since you have already repartitioned both datasets based on the 'id' column, Spark should be able to read the partitioning information from the parquet files.
However, it's possible that the default partitioning used by Spark during the join operation is different from the partitioning you specified earlier. You can explicitly set the number of partitions for the join operation using the repartition function or the coalesce function.
For example, if you want to join both datasets using 100 partitions and the 'id' column, you can do:
joined_dataset = dataset1.join(dataset2.repartition(100, 'id'), 'id').repartition(100)

This code ensures that both datasets are repartitioned in the same way before the join operation. The repartition(100) at the end ensures that the final result is also partitioned based on the 'id' column into 100 partitions.
Alternatively, you can also use coalesce to reduce the number of partitions after the join operation:
joined_dataset = dataset1.join(dataset2.repartition(100, 'id'), 'id').coalesce(100)

This code also ensures that both datasets are repartitioned in the same way before the join operation. The coalesce(100) at the end reduces the number of partitions to 100 after the join operation.

In the first approach, if I repartition both the datasets into 100 partitions, would that require shuffling, or would that be effectively a no-op? If it requires extensive shuffling, then I am not able to utilise the partitioning on id.
